# String to datetime in C# ["Mon Jul 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"]

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I have a situation in which user apply filter on reporedOn column data is filtered according to provided dates. But date is in below format which cause an exception.

```
Mon Jul 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I only want date and time. `for ex. 8/29/2018 19:43:0` How can I convert above date format to the date time in C#. I am looking for general solution which works for any timezone. I don't want to add any patch in the code by checking length of the string and use substring function and extract the required string and all.
Timezone may change from `India Standard Time to Pacific Time` or any other time zone.

Comment: You can try DateTime.ParseExact Method

_https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8_


  `var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "Mon Jul 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
    "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(India Standard Time)'",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: If user change the system time zone to PST then filter date change to: 
`Mon Aug 20 2018 09:49:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`

Answer (score 1):

I found the same solution as Bhushan in the comments did.

To convert the string

```
Mon Jul 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

to a C# DateTime object you can use:

```
String str = "Mon Jul 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";

DateTime dt= DateTime.ParseExact(str, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(India Standard Time)'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If your string does not include `(India Standard Time)` then you can remove the format provider:

```
String str = "Mon Jul 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530";

DateTime dt= DateTime.ParseExact(str, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K", null);
```

The 2 links I find useful for working with DateTime are [number 1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1) which provides a good summary for the DateTime formatting and [number 2](http://net-informations.com/q/faq/stringdate.html) which provides a good explanation of converting between strings and DateTime in C#.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: If user change the system time zone to PST then filter date change to:

`Mon Aug 20 2018 09:49:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`